# Difference on accelerometer from device to device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

i have just released a game for iPhone.
I have just tested in on two different iPhone 4, where every things is OK.

But now someone has reported to me that on iPhone 5/5S, the tilting is very sensitive and is veering to left.
I have tried googling this, but can't find any information about it. 
Have anyone here experienced this? Can there really be differences between those devices on something like this?

Comment: There are always differences with any analog measurement.

Comment: that is why good accelerometer games offer or even require calibration before first play

Comment: You should use a Low-pass filter, Low-pass filter provides a smoother form of a signal, removing the short-term fluctuations, and leaving the longer-term trend.